# Use Pointer In Defined Method

Tags: c++, c, pointers, c-preprocessor

I have been thinking of a way to solve this problem for quite some time, but I can't come up with a solution.

```
#define DmSetMemory(addr, len, data) DmSetMemory(addr, len, reverse_array_ret(data, len), DmLastError)
DmSetMemory(0, 0x100, buffer);
```

For example, I may want to set an actual byte array, which eventually works without problem. Then it gets to the issue when I want to set an immediate value, such as:

```
DmSetMemory(0, 0x4, 0x12345678);
```

This seems to be impossible, as that would be making it look as if I am pointing to the data at 0x12345678, but I want the number as a value itself. I am open to making another definition as well.

Comment: Why don't you use `DmSetVal(0, 0x4, (some_type *)0x12345678);`?

Comment: I suppose it's possible, I was just looking for some way without writing it like that.

Comment: what is the connection between `DmSetMemory` and `DmSetValue`? And what is `DmSetVal` ?

Comment: They're the same thing. It was a copying error.

Comment: @datOvetflow why do you hate casting? Do you really need to avoid casting?

Comment: Your edit "DmSetValue" -> "DmSetMemory" makes this a recursive macro (i.e. DmSetMemory defined to call DmSetMemory). I strongly doubt that this is actually the code you want to talk about.